# How to store a jquery variable in session/request/application in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile, jstl

I am developing a mobile application which contains multipage template, using jQuery Mobile and Spring MVC. I have a jsp that contain an anchor link; whenever I click the link `Pagebeforechange` event is called and a jQuery function is executed. I got an id from the link within the function and store it in a jQuery variable. Now I want to reuse the value from the jQuery variable in jstl `if` tag which is available in core tag library. How can I use that value? This is my jsp:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="m" id="menu">
   <c:import url="/headerPage.jsp"></c:import>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="h" data-inset="true">
        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
          <li>**<a href="#submenu1?id=${item.id}">**${item.name}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
       </div>
  <c:import url="footerPage.jsp"></c:import>
</div>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="m" id="submenu">
       <c:import url="/headerPage.jsp"></c:import>
        <div data-role="content">

           <c:set var="**testID**" scope="session" value="<div id='**result**'></div>"></c:set>  // here testID value printed 1st time but if I print value in 2nd time gives nothing

          <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="h" data-inset="true">

            <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">

                      <c:if test="${menu.key eq **testID**}"> // here testID is not working
                     <li><a href="#submenu2">${item.name}</a></li>
                      </c:if>    
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
           </div>
      <c:import url="footerPage.jsp"></c:import>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).bind("pagebeforechange",function(e, data) {

        if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
               var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage), re2 = /^#submenu1/; 
               var categoryName = u.hash.replace( /.*id=/, "" ); // how to store categoryName in session and use it later in <c:if> tag in jsp.
               var pageSelector = u.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

               jQuery('#**result**').text(categoryName);

           $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );   
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You could use jQuery to make a server request and store what needs storage server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need to do, but I saw the keywords jQuery, variable, store and session.

If you want a method to store variables page-wide, you can use $.cookie().

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie